# How to bypass "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger" prompt

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger prompts to select "*Possible Debuggers*",
only "*New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010*" is available,
I tick "*Set the currently selected debugger as the default*", click "*Yes*",

but, the dialog keeps being displayed every time.
I am debugging JavaScript in IE8 on Windows 7 x64.

**How do I bypass this prompt?**
*These registry values do not solve the problem*:

`[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]`
`"Auto"="1"`

`[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]`
`"Auto"="1"`

Comment: Also, why does the prompt appear beneath the current windows?

Comment: I have Windows 7 x64, too. **And this prompt is driving me nuts.**

Comment: What's the target application (debuggee)? .NET application or native application?

Comment: Is your intention to use the default debugger always, or would, say, generating a crash dump instead be acceptable?

Comment: @Paul Williams, I want to debug a JavaScript on HTML on an ActiveX browser. Basically I just one a prompt to debug and see the offending line of code. Just ONE prompt, yes or no.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just did this the other day.

In the following registry key:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Messenger\Client]`

Create 2 new DWORDs (`Right-click --> New --> DWORD Value`)

`PreventAutoRun` and `PreventRun`

Set both values to 1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing so directly from Visual Studio?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Scroll to "**Enabling or disabling Just-In-Time debugging**".

You can disable it only for Script if that's what you want.

Let me know how this works for you.