# How to disable JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to turn off javascript debugging in VS 2013 when using Internet Explorer?

I have already unchecked the option `Debugging -> Just-In-Time Debugging -> Script`, but whenever I start/debug my ASP.NET project (using IE), VS loads all script documents (js files) and shows them in the solution explorer.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792065/how-to-bypass-visual-studio-just-in-time-debugger-prompt

Comment: try this also, Tools -> Options -> Debugging and checking or unchecking the "Enable Just My Code" checkbox. let me know if this is not working for you

Comment: @cracker: checking/unchecking "Enable Just My Code" makes no difference

Comment: have you tried this: Tools -> Environment -> Web Browser -> Internet Explorer Options -> Advance -> From List Find out the Browser -> Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)  & Disable script debugging (other) (Check it default is uncheck)

Comment: This is also helpful but do in case of all the doors are closed :: Disable all script debugging in VS via: reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f

Answer (score 12):

Found an answer here that worked for me - a simple web.config tweak

http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/

You may do so either globally by changing the option from within Visual Studio:
[image]

Or by adding this line to your web.config files per project:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
        ...
```

Comment: There is good info in that article, but you should post the actual answer here and include the link as a supplement: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). See also: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Post the actual answer here and cite the link as well.  Don't just post a link.

Answer (score 0):

### List item

Open Visual Studio 2019 with your project

1. Select Tools
2. Select Options
3. Select Debugging [image]
4. Uncheck (Enable Java script debugging for ASP.Net(chrome,Edge and IE)) [image]